# Использование Sber GigaChat API

Tags: api, nlp

Подскажите пожалуйста как использовать Сбер GigaChat через API, если такой имеется, а если нет, то как можно использовать через прямое обращение к сайту gigachat через скрипт?

Comment: Пожалуйста, конкретизируйте ваш вопрос. Какую проблему вы решали, и с чем конкретно у вас возникла трудность при решении этой проблемы?

Comment: Пишут, что API будет доступна скоро. Подробности тут: https://developers.sber.ru/portal/products/gigachat?attempt=2#be-the-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для смертных API еще нет. Сам GigaChat выдает информацию о том, что доступы к API можно получить только написав на почту. Но он тот еще лжец, остается вариант со скриптами. Баны прилетят гарантировано, так что прячьтесь.
[image: Хм]

Comment: Из вашего ответа так и не стало понятно, существует ли API или это все ложь. Кроме этого, автор спрашивает, если нет API, то как обратиться на сайт через скрипт. На этот вопрос вы тоже не ответили.